# Three different Method calls of Python class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am reading [this article](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_object_oriented_programming.php). In this article a line says :

> For a Class C, an instance x of C and a method m of C the following
>   three method calls are equivalent:
>
> type(x).m(x, ...)
>
> C.m(x, ...)
>
> x.m(...)

I tried to convert this statement into program like this :

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,a,c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=c

    def m(self):
        d=self.a+self.b

x=C(1,2)
x.m()
print(type(x).m(x))
print(C.m(x))
print(x.m())
```

But i am getting no clue what these three methods meant and how they are working ?? If my program is using method wrong then please correct it.

## edit

I am not asking for modifications for this code , I am asking how those three methods are used and provide one example with each method calls.

If you can  provide proper example for each three method that would be very helpful for me.

Comment: You might want to have `m` return something, if you are going to try and print it.

Comment: Which version of python are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

If using python 2.7, you should derive `C` from `object` in order to get the correct type with `type(x)`, which knows the method `m`.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self,a,c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=c

    def m(self):
        return self.a+self.b

x=C(1,2)
x.m()
print(type(x).m(x))
print(C.m(x))
print(x.m())
```

I think in python 3, this is implicit. And yes, instead of calculating d, I just return the result - so you see something.

**Edit regarding your clarification:**

The three ways to call the method are shown for illustration. I would not see any obvious reason for not using `x.m()` if possible.  But in python, that is a shortcut for: Call the method `m` of the type of `x` on the instance `x`.
The `type(x).m(x)` is the most literal way to write what is going on. Now, `type(x)` is `C` (in python 3 or with new-style classes - derived from `object` - at least, else instance), so the first and second way of writing are equivalent as well.

Comment: I think he's on Python 3, judging from the `print` call. Either way, his tags are confusing so let's see what he answers to Scotts' comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your m isn't returning anything.

You want

```
def m(self):
    return self.a + self.b
```

Most likely within your `C` class